# Flink committing to kafka takes longer than the checkpoint interval

Tags: apache-flink

I'm having issues understanding why my flink job commits to kafka consumer is taking so long. I have a checkpoint of 1s and the following warning appears. I'm currently using version 1.14.

`Committing offsets to Kafka takes longer than the checkpoint interval. Skipping commit of previous offsets because newer complete checkpoint offsets are available. This does not compromise Flink's checkpoint integrity` 
Compared to some Kafka streams we have running, the commit latency takes around 100 ms.
Can you point me in the right direction? Are there any metrics that I can look at?

I tried to find metrics that could help to debug this

Answer (score 0):

Since Flink is continually committing offsets (sometimes overlapping in the cases of longer-running commits), network related blips and other external issues that cause the checkpoint to take longer can result in what you are seeing (a subsequent checkpoint is completed prior to the success of the previous one).

There are a handful of useful metrics related to checkpointing that you may want to explore that might help determine what's occurring:

- `lastCheckpointDuration` - The time it took to complete the last checkpoint (in milliseconds).
- `lastCheckpointSize` - The checkpointed size of the last checkpoint (in bytes), this metric could be different from lastCheckpointFullSize if incremental checkpoint or changelog is enabled.

Monitoring these as well as some of the [other checkpointing metrics](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/metrics/#checkpointing), along with task/job manager logs, might help you piece together a story for what caused the slower commit to take so long.

If you find that you are continually encountering this, you may look at adjusting the checkpointing configuration for the job to tolerate these longer durations.